# Bash скрипт перезагрузки Linux в определенное время

Tags: linux, bash

Доброго времени суток. Вопрос адептам Bash скриптинга. Подскажите пожалуйста, каким скриптом можно перезагружать систему каждый день в определенное время (к примеру в 21:00)?

Answer (score 8):

Через cron:

```
$ crontab -e -u root
21 0 * * * /sbin/shutdown -r now
# запуск задачи в 0:21
```

Comment: Всес спасибо. Попробую вначеле через крон.

Answer (score 0):

Так?

```
while true; do 
    HOUR=`date +%H`
    MINUTE=`date +%M`
    if [ $HOUR -eq "21" ] && [ $MINUTE -eq "00" ]; do 
        echo $HOUR $MINUTE
    fi
    sleep 60s
done
```

Comment: Скрипт может не отработать иногда. Дело в том, что sleep 60s будет спать как минимум 60 секунд. А может и чуточку больше. На одну секунду легко. Но так как в цикле есть ещё код, то может так произойти, что первая проверка сработает в 20:59:59, а вторая в 21:01:00. Самое простое исправление - поменять sleep на 30-40 секунд. Но крон лучше.